# ag-grid react cellEditor format

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I built a grid using ag-grid,
for one of the column I sent custom cell editor to render my own date component,
this column have also valueGetter to format the value to display,
my problem is: the cell editor get the formmated value, that returned from valueGetter, I want to have there the source value, how can I do it?
here is the definition of my columns object:

```
const columnsObject = [
      {
            field: 'date',
            colId: 'date',
            headerName: 'date',
            filter: true,
            sortable: true,
            unSortIcon: true,
            resizable: true,
            valueGetter: row => row.data.date && moment(row.data.date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'),
            editable: true,
            cellEditor: 'dateEditor',
            cellEditorParams: {
                name: 'startDate',
            }
     },
     {
            field: 'text',
            colId: 'text',
            headerName: 'text',
            filter: true,
            resizable: true,
            editable: true,
     },
];
```

My dateEditor should get the value with time (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm format), but in the view after stop editing it should be only time (YYYY-MM-DD format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using valueFormatter instead of valueGetter solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

A short explanation for everyone who looks for a solution to this problem: The Select Editor works in default with a unique set of values of the column. By formating these values in the valueGetter, the grid changes the values in its internal storage and uses these new Values for the Select Editor. So by using a valueFormatter instead, the data remains intact but gets displayed in the formatted style. This is, imo, the best way to approach this situation.